# "Value does not fall within expected range" - Visual Studio 2013 Configuration Properties

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

I'm trying to debug a program with arguments. To add arguments into the debugger I go to

> properties->configuration properties->debugging

and it's the first or second line on that page. However, whenever I click on "Debugging" an error appears that says "*Value does not fall within expected range.*" It happens on all my projects now regardless of what is in each project. I restarted my computer, reset all the settings in VS, and the error is still appearing. Help?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the solution options file(s) ".suo"?

Comment: Where would they be? Do you have a path?

Comment: You should be able to search for them in the same folder as your solution.

Comment: Solved by repairing VS2013. Not sure if it was necessary though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901514/value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range-when-trying-to-add-a-reference-i