# How do I fix this add reference issue in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net

When I attempt to add a reference I get the following error, it happens in every VS 2013 project, even new ones

"Value does not fall within the expected range"

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Value does not fall within the expected range" when trying to add a reference in a project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901514/value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range-when-trying-to-add-a-reference-i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try running

```
devenv /setup
```

from the command line.  It sounds as if your installation has a problem.