# What does this Nuget error mean, although package was successfully installed?

Tags: frameworks, automated-tests

I installed Golem v 2.2 into my project "Jupiter.Gole.ISM" by entering this command at the Package Manager Console.
PM> ***Install-Package Golem***

Even though the system reported that Golem 2.2.1 was successfully installed to my project, two errors had appeared:
1) Value does not fall within the expected range.
2) You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

...
...
Executing script file 'C:\Users\AChan\Documents\TestFrameworks\Jupiter.Gole.ISM\packages\Golem.2.2.1\tools\install.ps1'
InstallPath: C:\Users\AChan\Documents\TestFrameworks\Jupiter.Gole.ISM\packages\Golem.2.2.1
ToolsPath: C:\Users\AChan\Documents\TestFrameworks\Jupiter.Gole.ISM\packages\Golem.2.2.1\tools
Package: NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.ScriptPackage
Project: System.__ComObject
**Value does not fall within the expected range.**
At C:\Users\AChan\Documents\TestFrameworks\Jupiter.Gole.ISM\packages\Golem.2.2.1\tools\install.ps1:32 char:1
+ $mobFile = $project.ProjectItems.Item("Proxy").ProjectItems.Item("bro ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException

**You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.**
At C:\Users\AChan\Documents\TestFrameworks\Jupiter.Gole.ISM\packages\Golem.2.2.1\tools\install.ps1:33 char:1
+ $mobFile.Properties.Item("CopyToOutputDirectory").Value = 2
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

***Successfully installed 'Golem 2.2.1' to Jupiter.Gole.ISM***
PM>

Thanks for your feedback.
Arlene

Comment: Likely it was already answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901514/value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range-when-trying-to-add-a-reference-i Let me know if it helped

Comment: Yes it did.  Thank you.