# Installation of ProductivityPowerTools 2017 corrupts privateregistry.user.bin of VisualStudio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, productivity-power-tools

After installing ProductivityPowerTools 2017 in Visual Studio Professional 15.4.5 without admin rights on Windows7 I am not able to restart VisualStudio.

I get an access denied error for the package manager, pointing to ActivityLog.xml (see below).

Also see

[Package management initialization failed: Access Denied Error when opening Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46955197/package-management-initialization-failed-access-denied-error-when-opening-visua)

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/79829/access-denied-when-trying-to-enableinstall-an-exte.html

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/79829/access-denied-when-trying-to-enableinstall-an-exte.html

and ActivityLog.xml below.

If I delete

C:\Users\eis\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_551ecb7a\privateregistry.user.bin

I am able to restart VisualStudio. However, my settings are lost, which is very annoying.

=>Is there a way to repair privateregistry.user.bin?

(This is not addresse by the first referenced question.)

ActivityLog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ActivityLog.xsl"?>
<activity>
  <entry>
    <record>1</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.758</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 version: 15.0.27004.2010</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>2</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.758</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Log ID</description>
    <guid>{3BFB2164-4995-477D-9B0A-FF7A61B74431}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>3</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.761</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Running in isolation mode.</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>4</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.762</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Looking for master PkgDef file</description>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\master.pkgdef</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>5</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.765</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Creating PkgDefCacheNonVolatile</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>6</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.786</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Double-checking master pkgdef file</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>7</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.787</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>PkgDefManagement initialized</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>8</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.787</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>RootFolder</description>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>9</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.787</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>ShellFolder</description>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>10</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.787</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>PkgDefSearchPath</description>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.admin.pkgdef</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>11</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.787</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>ImageManifestSearchPath</description>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions;C:\Users\eis\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_551ecb7a\Extensions</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>12</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.787</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>ApplicationExtensionsFolder</description>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>13</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.787</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>&quot;ZeroImpact&quot; = dword:0, &quot;MergeRegistry&quot; = dword:3</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>14</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.790</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>Microsoft Visual Studio Appid Stub</source>
    <description>Application launch on system with DPI X/Y: 96/96</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>15</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.791</time>
    <type>Warning</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>No previous pkgdef cache data</description>
    <hr>80070002</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>16</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.791</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>PkgDefCache fast check: the timestamps are not current because the cache is either missing or corrupt.</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>17</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.791</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>PkgDefManagement: PkgDef cache fast check returned false; cache will be regenerated.</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>18</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.791</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Searching for PkgDefs from search path</description>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.admin.pkgdef</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>19</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.905</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Missing folder or file during PkgDef scan</description>
    <hr>80030002</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.admin.pkgdef</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>20</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.905</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Discovered 265 PkgDef files</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>21</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.905</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>PkgDefCache flags</description>
    <hr>00013801</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>22</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.905</time>
    <type>Warning</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>No previous pkgdef cache data</description>
    <hr>80070002</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>23</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.905</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>PkgDefCache fast check: the timestamps are not current because the cache is either missing or corrupt.</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>24</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.905</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>CPkgDefCacheNonVolatileBase: PkgDef cache is out of date.</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>25</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.905</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Initializing non-volatile pkgdef cache</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>26</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.905</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>InitializeCache: Deleting configuration if it exists</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>27</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.905</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>InitializeCache: Deleting abandoned volatile cache</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>28</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.905</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>InitializeCache: Pre initializing cache</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>29</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.905</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>InitializeCache: Importing config package defs</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>30</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.905</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading discovered pkgdef files</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>31</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.906</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Importing pkgdef file</description>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\master.pkgdef</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>32</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.908</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Importing pkgdef file</description>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\DSLTextTemplatingRegistry_x86.pkgdef</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>33</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.909</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Failed to process PkgDef file</description>
    <hr>80070005 - E_ACCESSDENIED</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\DSLTextTemplatingRegistry_x86.pkgdef</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>34</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.909</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>PkgDef loading aborted</description>
    <hr>80070005 - E_ACCESSDENIED</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>35</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.909</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>CPkgDefCacheNonVolatileBase: PkgDef cache creation failed. Going volatile and trying again.</description>
    <hr>80070005 - E_ACCESSDENIED</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>36</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.909</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Going volatile: Recalculated pkgdef configuration root</description>
    <path>Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_551ecb7a_Config_2072</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>37</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.909</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>On Windows 7 - keep REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>38</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.909</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Initializing non-volatile pkgdef cache</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>39</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.909</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>InitializeCache: Deleting configuration if it exists</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>40</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.909</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>InitializeCache: Deleting abandoned volatile cache</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>41</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.910</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>InitializeCache: Pre initializing cache</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>42</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.910</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>InitializeCache: Importing config package defs</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>43</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.910</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading discovered pkgdef files</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>44</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.910</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Importing pkgdef file</description>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\master.pkgdef</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>45</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.912</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Importing pkgdef file</description>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\DSLTextTemplatingRegistry_x86.pkgdef</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>46</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.913</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Failed to process PkgDef file</description>
    <hr>80070005 - E_ACCESSDENIED</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\DSLTextTemplatingRegistry_x86.pkgdef</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>47</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.913</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>PkgDef loading aborted</description>
    <hr>80070005 - E_ACCESSDENIED</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>48</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.913</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Error or timeout while initializing non-volatile pkgdef cache</description>
    <hr>80070005 - E_ACCESSDENIED</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>49</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.913</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>PkgDefManagement startup complete</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>50</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.914</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Configuration is Volatile.</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>51</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.914</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Configuration file to be used for CLR initialization</description>
    <path>C:\Users\eis\AppData\Local\Temp\devEB50.tmp</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>52</record>
    <time>2017/11/30 16:07:29.914</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Failure calling FinishInitialize.</description>
    <hr>80070005 - E_ACCESSDENIED</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
</activity>
```

Comment: This is a bug report for Microsoft, you posted it in the wrong place.  Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Package management initialization failed: Access Denied Error when opening Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46955197/package-management-initialization-failed-access-denied-error-when-opening-visua)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It is a VisualStudio bug, that has been resolved with version 15.5 (released yesterday)
- I was not able to repair the settings file privateregistry.user.bin.