# Package management initialization failed. When launching Visual Studio 2017 (15.7.2)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

After installing VS2017 Community ver. 15.7.2 on Win 7 64-bit, following error was found when launching VS2017 with or without admin privilage:

> Package management initialization failed.
>
> You can get more information by examining the file:
>   C:\Users\NAME\Appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_5024a39e\ActivityLog.xml

These are the errors found in ActivityLog.xml file:

> Infos:  Could not find ConfigurationChanged timestamp.
>
> Error: merging configuration file     C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_5024a39e\devenv.exe.config
>
> Error: merging configuration file
>             C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Temp\dev6FC4.tmp
>
> Error: merging configuration file
>             C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Temp\dev6FC5.tmp
>
> Error: merging configuration file
>             C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Temp\dev6FC6.tmp
>
> Error: Configuration file merge failed.
>
> Error: Failure calling FinishInitialize.

Tried to install VS2017 Enterprise as well as the VS2017 Community 15.6.7 and got the same errors.

There is a similar problem answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46955197/package-management-initialization-failed-access-denied-error-when-opening-visua) but it doesn't work for me.

Any input is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i solve that doing this

- Uninstall Visual Studio 2017 and other Visual Studios
- Delete C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio
- Uninstall any Visual C++
- Look for any Visual Studio Key on the Regedit and delete
- Delete C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2017 (Backup your projects)
- Delete C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Visual Studio\15.##
- Update your Windows and restart your pc
- Install Visual Studio 2017 again
- Try to open, and one error apears
- Copy the devenv.exe.config file locate in the root of the IdE  to 
  C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Visual Studio\15.##
- Try to open again
- Try to open in safe mode
- Try devenv.exe /resetSettings
- Try to repair Visual Studio Again

For me works  :) !

Comment: My Visual Studio 2017 stop working after while, and i have to do this. Download a iso of Windows 10 and run this command from cmd with adm privilegies Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:F:\ (F is my virtual dvd drive With Windows 10 iso Mounted)