# VS project load error after changing windows 10 user account

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I recently changed my Windows 10 user account structure and signed in with a local Windows 10 account instead of my usual Microsoft account. Since this change, one of my asp.NET MVC5 projects will not load. It states that `"The project requires user input. Reload the project for more information"`.

[image]

When I try to reload the project I get another error:

```
C:\Users\user\source\repos\repo-admin-xx\BookingSystem\BookingSystem.csproj : error  : The project file could not be loaded. Root element is missing.  C:\Users\user\source\repos\repo-admin-xx\BookingSystem\BookingSystem.csproj
```

[image: Value does not fall within the expected range.]

The BookingSystem.csproj file is present in the above folder so I am not too sure what to do next. All ideas to help fix are appreciated

Comment: Is the app is hosted in IIS

Comment: Yes, I test locally with IIS. The web app is deployed to AWS and works fine

Comment: If you're running using IIS, you should run Visual studio as Administrator. Seems that's the issue.

Comment: Thanks Anuraj but I have tried that and still the same issue

Comment: old post but relevant to the version of VS you're using: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901514/value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range-when-trying-to-add-a-reference-i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it was indeed an error with the .csproj file which became corrupt in some way, that was causing the problem; not sure of the exact cause. I reverted back to a previous Git version of the same. csproj file and the project loads again like it should