# Beckhoff TcHmi - VS2019 Professional - Error "Value does not fall within the expected range"

Tags: twincat

I have created tchmi Project in VS2019 Professional(win10).
If i click any of the files in the project (e.g Desktop.view, Images) following error appears.

I didn't try on any other VS.
TcHmi is working on the TwinCAT XAR shell.
I need to use VS2019 in this case as I need to develop server extensions.

[image]

Please let me know the solution. I have spent a good amount of time trying to solve it but not successful.

Comment: Did you try any of [these suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901514/value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range-when-trying-to-add-a-reference-i)?

Comment: Hello @Roald, I tried most of the suggestions but no luck. Also non are concerning to tcHmi.

Comment: Too bad. Yes most are not related to TcHMI, but the error seems also more like a more general visual studio one than a specific TcHMI one.

Comment: I also observed "VS2019 not responding while TWINCAT is being installed" i always click kill task to continue the twincat Installation process. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69812246/vs2019-not-responding-while-twincat-is-being-installed). Is these two issues are interlinked?

Comment: I would always first close visual studio before installing TwinCAT.

Comment: Hello @Roald, that´s right and i too followed the same process. But VS will pop up during TwiCat Installation.

Comment: You should leave that running. At that point the TwinCAT installer is integrating TwinCAT into Visual Studio. So you should reinstall TwinCAT and leave Visual Studio running when it pops up.

Comment: that´s Right. I do follow that.

Comment: I removed all the software’s and reinstalled again. This is 5th reinstallation and surprisingly it worked this time.