# VS2019 not responding while TWINCAT is being installed

Tags: twincat

What would be the reasons for VS2019 Professional not to respond while twincat TWINCAT:v3.1.4024.22 being installed on WIN10 machine.
I tried many times to reinstall and its same result.

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you are not closing Visual Studio while installing TwinCAT?  Maybe I am missing something, but it seems like the TwinCAT installer may need to access Visual Studio files and having the software open could cause an error.

Comment: Probably due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69774087/beckhoff-tchmi-vs2019-professional-error-value-does-not-fall-within-the-exp#comment123403074_69774087).

Comment: I removed all the software’s and reinstalled again. This is 5th reinstallation and surprisingly it worked this time.